# Let us duplicate a filter in Filtered Questions

Tags: feature-request, support, stackexchange.com, tag-filters

On the Stack Exchange "Filtered Questions" page, how can I duplicate a filter I have made already? I would like to use that filter as a template for other filters.

Comment: There's a "Filtered Questions" page?

Comment: @musefan: [There is.](http://stackexchange.com/filters/77548/bug-reports-and-feature-requests)

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: Sweeet. Didn't know you could browse questions from multiple sites like that. That might have to be my new hiding place

Comment: After having a play around, it doesn't look like it is possible. If you already know that, and you are indeed trying to get it implemented, then re-tag it as "feature request". It would probably get more votes then

Comment: I'm a fairly new user, so I assumed this was a feature already there! But after looking through some other questions, I'll add the tag as you suggested - thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is one such way I know that you can achieve this functionality, but it requires a 'filter buddy'...

1. Get yourself a 'filter buddy' (somebody who also has a StackExchange account)
2. Send them the URL of your filter that you want to copy
3. When they opens the filter, it will say something like "You are viewing a filter created by another user.", with a button to "Save to my filters" - have your 'filter buddy' click this
4. Get your 'filter buddy' to send you the new URL for the filter they just acquired
5. When you open the URL, you will get prompted with the same "Save to my filters" option - Do this
6. Open your new duplicate filter, and click the "Edit" option (next to the title), and configure your new cloned-from-template filter

Not ideal I know, but if you want a dedicated feature then you should consider raising this as a "feature request" instead (which I notice you have since re-tagged)

Comment: Not bad, but an easier way would be nice! Especially for those of us who don't have filter buddies or friends of any type :-\